# Failed to output dataimport raw status output to Json

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I tried the following urls to output status to json but to no avail. Pleae help.

--option 1- results to endless loop or loading of page
http://host:port/solr/#/collection/dataimport?command=status&wt=json

--option 2- results to display of page instead of json.
http://host:port/solr/#/collection/dataimport//dataimport?command=rawstatus-output&wt=json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `#` character from the URLs. So:

`http://[host]:[port]/solr/[collectionName]/dataimport?command=status&wt=json`

Comment: Thank you very much. I always thought that I should retain it because of the cloud structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. I thought i should retain it because of the cloud env.